# Web crawler in R with heading and summary

Tags: r, web, rvest

I'm trying to extract links from [here](http://money.howstuffworks.com/business-profiles.htm) with the article heading and a brief summary of each link.
The output should have the article heading and the brief summary of each article which is on the same page.

I'm able to get the links. Can you please suggest how can i get heading and summary for each link. Please see my code below.

```
install.packages('rvest')

#Loading the rvest package
library('rvest')
library(xml2)


#Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
url <- 'http://money.howstuffworks.com/business-profiles.htm'


webpage <- read_html(url)

pg <- read_html(url)

head(html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "a"), "href"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `purrr` to inspect each node and extract the relevant information:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

url <- 'http://money.howstuffworks.com/business-profiles.htm'
articles <- read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes('.infinite-item > .media') %>% 
    map_df(~{
        title <- .x %>% 
            html_node('.media-heading > h3') %>% 
            html_text()

        head <- .x %>% 
            html_node('p') %>% 
            html_text()

        link <- .x %>% 
            html_node('p > a') %>% 
            html_attr('href')

        data.frame(title, head, link, stringsAsFactors = F)
    })

head(articles)
#>                                                             title
#> 1                              How Amazon Same-day Delivery Works
#> 2              10 Companies That Completely Reinvented Themselves
#> 3                                10 Trade Secrets We Wish We Knew
#> 4                                           How Kickstarter Works
#> 5                          Can you get rich selling stuff online?
#> 6 Are the Golden Arches really supposed to be giant french fries?
#>                                                                                                                                                           head
#> 1                 The Amazon same-day delivery service aims to get your package to you in no time at all. Learn how Amazon same-day delivery works. SeeÂ moreÂ Â»
#> 2 You might be surprised at what some of today's biggest companies used to do. Here are 10 companies that reinvented themselves from HowStuffWorks. SeeÂ moreÂ Â»
#> 3              Trade secrets are often locked away in corporate vaults, making their owners a fortune. Which trade secrets are the stuff of legend? SeeÂ moreÂ Â»
#> 4        Kickstarter is a service that utilizes crowdsourcing to raise funds for your projects. Learn about how Kickstarter works at HowStuffWorks. SeeÂ moreÂ Â»
#> 5                                                   Can you get rich selling your stuff online? Find out more in this article by HowStuffWorks.com. SeeÂ moreÂ Â»
#> 6     Are McDonald's golden arches really suppose to be giant french fries? Check out this article for a brief history of McDonald's golden arches. SeeÂ moreÂ Â»
#>                                                                    link
#> 1           http://money.howstuffworks.com/amazon-same-day-delivery.htm
#> 2 http://money.howstuffworks.com/10-companies-reinvented-themselves.htm
#> 3                   http://money.howstuffworks.com/10-trade-secrets.htm
#> 4                        http://money.howstuffworks.com/kickstarter.htm
#> 5    http://money.howstuffworks.com/can-you-get-rich-selling-online.htm
#> 6                   http://money.howstuffworks.com/mcdonalds-arches.htm
```

Obligatory comment: In this case I saw no disclaimer against harvesting on their [Terms and conditions](http://www.howstuffworks.com/terms-and-conditions.htm), but always be sure to check the terms of a site before scraping it.

Comment: Thank you and please pardon my ignorance. I'm getting this error                  Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’
> head(articles)
Error in head(articles) : object 'articles' not found

Comment: @alyoung3344 Sounds like you need to install and/or load dplyr. `install.packages("dplyr"); library(dplyr)`